# Ordered traversal of Map

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary

I have a datastructure which is a `Map` of `Objects`.
This alows me to access to my object using keys, which is something I need.
However I'd like to be able to traverse my structure using a specific order.

Example:

```
function Container()
{
    this.data   = new Map();
    this.at     = function(objID)   {   return this.data.get(objID);    }
    this.insert = function(obj)     {   this.data.set(obj.id, obj);     }
    this.remove = function(obj)     {   this.data.delete(obj.id);       }
    this.size   = function()        {   return this.data.size;          }
    this.values = function()        {   return this.data.values();      }
}
var cnt = new Map();
cnt.set({id: 1, order:3});
cnt.set({id: 2, order:1});
cnt.set({id: 3, order:2});
```

I'd like to add a `sortedValues` method that alows me to access all object in order.

I tried doing

```
this.data.values().sort(function(a,b){ return a.order > b.order; });
```

But the sort method is availlable on `Array` and not on `Iterators`.
How can I build an ordered iterator ? Otherwise how could I convert the `.values()` iterator to an `Array` ?

Comment: It would help give you a good suggestion if you said how often you modify the Map, and how often you access it. Performance might matter.

Comment: (especially since you already have a wrapper around it, it should be easy to replace the Map implementation with a more suitable data structure)

Comment: Accessing and modifying the maps will happen pretty often. However iterating will happen only on rare occasion (and with size that might be small : <100)

Comment: I see. Sorting does make sense in that case. May I ask why you're using a Map instead of a plain Object? are the IDs not strings (or numbers as in your example)?

Comment: IDs are int ... I supose I could use object then (I'm comming from c++ and I often forget object are not struct ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your IDs are integers, you don't realy need a Map. From plain objects used as hash tables you can get an actual Array of keys with Object.keys(data) or [Object.ownPropertyNames(data)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). Here's an example using some other cool Object features:

```
var cnt = Object.create({}, {
  length: { value: 0, enumerable: false, configurable: false },
  set: {
      value: function(obj)
      {
        if(!(obj.id in this)) this.length++
        this[obj.id]=obj
      },
      writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false
  },
  remove: {
      value: function(obj)
      {
        if(obj.id in this){
          this.length--
          delete this[obj.id]
        }
      },
      writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false
  },
  sorted: {
      value: function()
      {
        return Object.keys(this).sort(function(a,b){return this[a].order - this[b].order}.bind(this))
          .map(function(id){return this[id]}.bind(this))
      },
      writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false
  }
})

cnt.set({id: 1, order:3})
cnt.set({id: 2, order:1})
cnt.set({id: 3, order:2})

console.log(cnt.sorted())
```

Comment: Depending on how often you use the "length", you could simplify the `set` and `remove` methods and instead define a getter for `length` that returns `Object.keys(this).length`